# Laradock 404 Not Found Files Apache2

Tags: php, laravel, apache, apache2, laradock

I'm trying to access these public files in laradock by Apache2.

However it turns out 404 NOT FOUND.

Someone any idea what the problem could be?

The structure is like below

```
 --docker
     --laradock
     --demo
        --project_a
            --public
        --project_b
            --public  
        --project_c
            --public
```

and the ServerName are projecta.test, projectb.test, projectc.test.

laradock/apache2/sites/projecta.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName projecta.test
  DocumentRoot /var/www/demo/project_a/public/
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

  <Directory "/var/www/demo/project_a/public/">
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

laradock/apache2/Dockerfile

```
    FROM webdevops/apache:ubuntu-18.04

    LABEL maintainer="Eric Pfeiffer <computerfr33k@users.noreply.github.com>"

    ARG DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/
    ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=php-fpm
    ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=9000
    ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_TIMEOUT=60
    ARG APACHE_INSTALL_HTTP2=false

    ENV WEB_PHP_SOCKET=${PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}:${PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}
    ENV WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=${DOCUMENT_ROOT}
    ENV APACHE_HTTP2=${APACHE_INSTALL_HTTP2}
    ENV WEB_PHP_TIMEOUT=${PHP_UPSTREAM_TIMEOUT}

    ENV LOG_STDOUT=/var/log/apache2/access.log

    ENV LOG_STDERR=/var/log/apache2/error.log

    EXPOSE 80 443

    WORKDIR /var/www/

    COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites/vhost.conf

    ADD ./startup.sh /opt/startup.sh

    ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/entrypoint.sh"]

    CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/startup.sh"]

    EXPOSE 80 443

    ARG APACHE_FOR_MAC_M1=false

    RUN if [ ${APACHE_FOR_MAC_M1} = true ]; then \
        # Change application source from deb.debian.org to aliyun source
        wget -O "/usr/local/bin/go-replace" "https://github.com/webdevops/goreplace/releases/download/1.1.2/gr-arm64-linux" && \
        chmod +x "/usr/local/bin/go-replace" && \
        "/usr/local/bin/go-replace" --version \
    ;fi
```

laradock/apache2/vhost.conf

```
Include /etc/apache2/sites/*.conf
```

Comment: 3 things: 1) re-read Laradocks documentation on the project directory. If you put your projects in `../projects` then there's an easier way of handling them in your docker-compose.yml. 2) Your Dockerfile is from a fork of Laradock from Ling long time ago. Check laradocks official github page, it might help. 3) your document_root is `/var/www` but in your project_a your root is `/var/www/demo/project_a/public/` re-think that solution